# Reading big-endian binary files containing mixed types

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, binary, endianness

How should I read a big-endian binary file containing mixed types in Python?

I am working with a file generated in java, and I wish to read it in Python. The file has this format:

Header:

```
dynamics duration (double)
number of spins (double)
tmax (double)
```

Data (one line per spin per update):

```
time (double)
spin index (int)
spin x (double)
spin y (double)
spin z (double)
```

(double refers to a signed double-precision 8-byte floating point number. int refers to a signed, 32bit (4 byte) integer.)

I am currently trying:

```
    for i in range(15):
        print struct.unpack('>f', file.read(4))[0]
```

But the data I read out does not make sense...

Comment: Why are you reading only 4 bytes? To read a double, you need to pass in 8 bytes and use format character `d`.

Comment: Thank you! And format character i for int of course... That was what I needed to realize.

Comment: can you please post the answer ? I also have some same problem. I have a big-endian file with many columns in one row. and want to convert the whole file to decimals. The format was given to me like this . `col1       s370fib4.
col2       s370fib4.
col3        s370fib2.
col4     float4.`